# c to delphi conversion of structure

Tags: c++, c, delphi

can somebody tell me does my conversation from c to delphi is well:

c code

```
struct nfq_data {
    /* packet_hdr - it HAVE to be the same as struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr */
    struct {
        uint32_t packet_id; /* unique ID of packet in queue in network order */
        uint16_t hw_protocol; /* hw protocol in network order */
        uint8_t hook; /* netfilter hook */
    } packet_hdr;
    /* packet_hw - it HAVE to be the same as struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hw */
    struct {
        uint16_t hw_addrlen; /* len of hw_addr in network order */
        uint16_t _pad;
        uint8_t hw_addr[8];
    } packet_hw;
    /* tm */
    struct {
        long sec;
        long usec;
    } tm;

    uint32_t if_index; /* Unique iface id */
    uint32_t verdict; /* Netfilter verdict value */
    uint32_t mark; /* Mark value */
    uint8_t if_name[IFNAMSIZE]; /* Name of incoming or outgoing iface */
    uint32_t data_len; /* Length of packet */
    uint8_t payload[0]; /* packet data */
};
```

where

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned __int16 uint16_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;
```

delphi

```
_packet_hdr = record
    packet_id: Cardinal;
    hw_protocol: Word;
    hook: Byte;
  end;

  _packet_hw = record
    hw_addrlen: Word;
    _pad: Word;
    hw_addr: array[0..7] of byte;
  end;

  _tm = record
    sec: Int64;
    usec: Int64;
  end;

  pnfq_data = ^nfq_data;
  nfq_data = record
    packet_hdr: _packet_hdr;
    packet_hw: _packet_hw;
    tm: _tm;
    if_index: Cardinal;
    verdict: Cardinal;
    mark: Cardinal;
    if_name: array[0..254] of Byte;
    data_len: Cardinal;
    payload: PChar; //TBytes;
  end;

    packet_hdr: _packet_hdr;
    packet_hw: _packet_hw;
```

I am receiving well, but after those nothing well.

Thanks in advance

Bojan

Comment: I think you shouldn't typedef `uintN_t` identifiers. If you have C99 you're overwriting system identifiers (in `<inttypes.h>`); and if you haven't you're just waiting for something bad to happen when you finally change to C99.

Comment: There is not enough information to locate the problem. Find the first location in your code that behaves badly and put that code here. Describe here current behavior and desired behavior. Add some memory dumps if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint8_t payload[0];
```

Is that really a pointer(as in your delphi-code) or an inplace array of size 0 used to represent data coming after the header

And you should mark your records as `packed`. <s>I don't think it makes a difference in your specific code, but</s> it is good practice since the packing rules are easy to get wrong, might change and not everybody knows them.
It probably makes a difference because packet_hdr is 7 bytes larges when packed, so the following packet_hw starts at offset 7 when packed, and probably at 8 when aligned.

Comment: "Is that really a pointer" Good question. Also that is answer for Payload, last field. "Packed" solved everything before, and payload is the start of array where have to take the data, with the length defined in data_len. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to surround your struct with `#pragma pack(push,1)` / `#pragma pack(pop)` (if we are talking about Visual Studio).

Comment: Yes, we are speaking about Visual Studio. The code is inside #pragma pack(1)/#pragma pack()

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment ***"I am receiving well, but after those nothing well."***

I assume you are getting data from a "C" application -

Have a look at "**Record field aliment**" in the "delphi compiler" code generation options screen
There are a number of different options such as "Quad Word" or "Word" align.